# Extract and assign dataframes from a list

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I am trying to split a dataset by group and assign each grouped dataset to its own object. I can use the code below to split the dataset.

```
library(dplyr)

grouped_df <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  group_split()
```

Where I'm struggling is how to extract and assign each grouped dataset. The closest I've gotten is something like this:

```
for(i in grouped_df){
  assign(x = paste("data_subset", seq(1, 3), sep = "_"), value = i) 
}
```

However, the for-loop above only works for the first grouped-dataset and produces the following warnings:

```
In assign(x = paste("data", seq(1, 3), sep = "_"), value = i) : 
only the first element is used as variable name
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: I'm curious: Why do you need to assign them to a new variable? You could access them easily by `grouped_df[[1]]`, `grouped_df[[2]]` etc.

Comment: `list2env` may help, but I agree that it's almost always easier to work with related data if you leave it in a list rather than create a bunch of separate variables in your global namespace. If you are new to R I strongly suggest you avoid `assign()`. It just makes more trouble than it's usually worth.

Comment: If you want a named list perhaps you prefer `split(iris,f = iris$Species)` (that is, `group_split()` doesn't returned a named list, directly). You could `list2env(split(iris,f=iris$Species),envion=.GlobalEnv)`, but agree with colleagues re keeping in list.

Comment: I believe I need to split the data as a workaround to memory limitations that arise when using stplanr::overline(). The function's documentation suggests doing so when dealing with very large datasets.